# Why setText() of EditText is not working?

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I want to put a string in a EditText in a AlertDialog,which is in a onItemClick Listener with a ListVIew.Here is the part of code

```
dialogbuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this)

          .setTitle(R.string.title_connect_dialog)

          .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_connect,null))

          .setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override

              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              }

          })

          .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override

              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
              }

          })

          .create();



  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_connect, null);

 edit1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.devicename);

   edit2 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.deviceadd);



private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {



  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {

        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();

        name = info.substring(0,info.length() - 18);

        address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        dialogbuilder.show();

            edit1.setText(name);

            edit2.setText(address);

       }

};
```

When I run the project,there is nothing in the EditText!It does not work!But there is no exception or error.I tried only set  text in the XML file can work.I replaced EditText with TextView ,but is not work too.
Are there something wrong in logical?Thank you for reading.

Comment: Where are `name` and `address` even defined?

Comment: remove  dialogbuilder.show(); from above of eddit1.setText(name) and place it after eddit2.setText(address)

Comment: In the onItemClickListner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as view instance for accessing Views form Dialog layout which you are passing in `setView` method of `AlertDialog.Builder` change:

```
  .setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_connect,null))
```

to

```
  .setView(view)
```

**EDIT:**

or instead of inflate layout again to access views you should use `dialogbuilder` instance to initialize EditText as:

```
edit1 = (EditText)dialogbuilder.findViewById(R.id.devicename);
edit2 = (EditText)dialogbuilder.findViewById(R.id.deviceadd);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are showing the `Dialog` before setting the text

```
dialogbuilder.show();

edit1.setText(name);
edit2.setText(address);
```

Try changing that around

```
edit1.setText(name);
edit2.setText(address);
dialogbuilder.show();
```